# Extracting the diagonal from dfs in a list of dfs in R using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, data-wrangling

I got data from eight survey sites A to H and nine years (1999, 2000, 2001, 2006, 2008, 2011, 2013, 2016, 2019).

```
library (dplyr)
# create column names for years
years <- c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2006, 2008, 2011, 2013, 2016, 2019)

# create an empty data frame with sites A:H in the first column
df <- data.frame(Site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"),
                 matrix(NA, nrow = 8, ncol = length(years), 
                        dimnames = list(NULL, years)))

# remove the X before the year in the column names
colnames(df)[-1] <- years

# generate random numbers for each site and year
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i, 2:ncol(df)] <- runif(length(years))
}
```

I calculated the Euclidean distances of the survey sites and years, stored this matrix as a dataframe and split it into a list of dataframes by `Site`

```
# gather to long form to calculate dist.
df = df %>% gather (key = "Year", value = "Value", c(2:last_col()))

# calculate dist and set as a df
dist.df <- df %>% 
  mutate(YrSi = paste(substr(Year, 3, 4), Site)) %>%
  select(-Year, -Site) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "YrSi") %>%
  dist() %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as.data.frame()

#split dist.df to a list of dfs per site

dist.df.list = dist.df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("YrSi") %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year", "Site"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate (Year =  as.numeric (ifelse (Year == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year),sprintf("20%s", Year)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  gather(key = "YrSi", value = "Dist", c(3:last_col())) %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year2", "Site2"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate (Year2 =  as.numeric (ifelse (Year2 == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year2),sprintf("20%s", Year2)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  arrange(Site, Year, Site2, Year2) %>%
  spread (key = "Year2", value = "Dist") %>% 
  group_by(Site, Site2) %>% 
  subset (Site == Site2) %>%
  relocate (Year, .after = Site2) %>% 
  group_split()
```

I want to create a new datafame `result.df` that shows the first column as `Site` and then each column is a survey year from 2000 onwards (see below). Under each column, the distance between the survey year to survey the year before for a given site will be shown. For instance: under 2000 the distance between 1999 and 2000 will be shown for each site; under 2008 the distance between that year and 2006 will be shown; etc. To simplify, I want to extract the diagonals as highlighted in this image:

[image: The Eucleadian distances between consecutive survey years at site A]

To make it more manageable, I gathered the data in a long-form so that instead of a column per each year there is the `Year` column and a `Year2` column:

```
dist.df.list = dist.df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("YrSi") %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year", "Site"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate (Year =  as.numeric (ifelse (Year == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year),sprintf("20%s", Year)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  gather(key = "YrSi", value = "Dist", c(3:last_col())) %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year2", "Site2"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate (Year2 =  as.numeric (ifelse (Year2 == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year2),sprintf("20%s", Year2)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  arrange(Site, Year, Site2, Year2) %>%
  spread (key = "Year2", value = "Dist") %>% 
  group_by(Site, Site2) %>% 
  subset (Site == Site2) %>%
  relocate (Year, .after = Site2) %>% 
  gather (key="Year2", value = "dist", c(4:last_col())) %>%
  group_split()
```

Now to generate the `result.df`

```
# Initialize an empty data frame to store the results
result.df <- data.frame(Site = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through each data frame in the list
for(i in 1:length(dist.df.list)) {
  # Extract the site name
  site <- dist.df.list[[i]]$Site[1]
  
  # Initialize a new row for the site in the result data frame
  new.row <- data.frame(Site = site, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  # Loop through each survey year and extract the distance between consecutive years
  for(j in c(2000, 2001, 2006,2008, 2011, 2013, 2016, 2019)) {
    col.name <- as.character(j)
    if(col.name %in% colnames(dist.df.list[[i]])) {
      # Extract the distance value from the test data frame
      dist <- dist.df.list[[i]] %>% 
        filter(Year2 == j) %>% 
        select(dist) %>% 
        pull()
      
      # If the distance value is missing, set it to NA
      if(is.na(dist)) {
        new.row[[col.name]] <- NA
      } else {
        # Otherwise, add the distance value to the new row
        new.row[[col.name]] <- dist
      }
    } else {
      # If the distance column doesn't exist, set the value to NA
      new.row[[col.name]] <- NA
    }
  }
  
  # Add the new row to the result data frame
  result.df <- rbind(result.df, new.row)
}
```

```
result.df

  Site 2000 2001 2006 2008 2011 2013 2016 2019
1    A   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2    B   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3    C   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4    D   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5    E   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6    F   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
7    G   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
8    H   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Why am I getting NA's instead of the distances?
Is there a more simplified way of doing that?

Comment: You might want `library(tidyverse)` since you rely on `tidyr::gather` and `tibble::rownames_to_column`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking to compare each year value against the next year value, the tricky part being that the years are non-uniformly distributed. One way to deal with this is to treat the years as factors, and then convert those to numeric, so 2001 is `year_index` 3, 2006 is `year_index` 4, etc. Then we can join each row to the one with the same site and one lower `year_index`.

This makes for a much shorter approach.

Starting from your initial `df` in the first chunk before you reshape it:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df_long = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Site, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Value") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.factor(Year),
         Year_index = as.numeric(Year))
  
df_long %>%
  inner_join(df_long %>% mutate(Year_index = Year_index - 1), 
            by = join_by(Site, Year_index)) %>%
  transmute(Site, Year.x, diff = abs(Value.y - Value.x)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year.x, values_from = diff)
```

Result (the first row matches the highlighted values in the question)

```
# A tibble: 8 × 9
  Site  `1999` `2000` `2001`  `2006` `2008`   `2011` `2013` `2016`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     0.501  0.379  0.474  0.0574  0.895  0.483    0.364   0.341
2 B     0.500  0.503  0.224  0.105   0.470  0.797    0.654   0.204
3 C     0.627  0.0650 0.197  0.0523  0.354  0.339    0.0528  0.164
4 D     0.305  0.142  0.816  0.0607  0.212  0.105    0.771   0.453
5 E     0.542  0.102  0.0866 0.0888  0.272  0.000822 0.0449  0.216
6 F     0.0942 0.233  0.200  0.592   0.812  0.396    0.357   0.677
7 G     0.354  0.0790 0.626  0.142   0.521  0.291    0.570   0.289
8 H     0.540  0.366  0.362  0.00233 0.0180 0.355    0.315   0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we may do this easily by subtracting two equal sized datasets by removing the column from the start and end

```
cbind(df[1], abs(df[-1][-ncol(df[-1])] - df[-1][-1]))
```

-output

```
 Site       1999       2000       2001        2006       2008         2011       2013      2016
1    A 0.50072762 0.37932821 0.47404048 0.057449880 0.89491078 0.4825489887 0.36431356 0.3409840
2    B 0.50021861 0.50349919 0.22423648 0.104937233 0.46970872 0.7969002877 0.65373724 0.2040282
3    C 0.62658293 0.06496433 0.19673591 0.052296592 0.35376296 0.3385639775 0.05282467 0.1644644
4    D 0.30498228 0.14204609 0.81591059 0.060725187 0.21159377 0.1047621393 0.77085373 0.4531823
5    E 0.54205160 0.10177307 0.08655522 0.088825763 0.27174631 0.0008220095 0.04487888 0.2164007
6    F 0.09422804 0.23292835 0.19998981 0.591855075 0.81199655 0.3963689075 0.35672477 0.6770256
7    G 0.35441659 0.07899974 0.62577621 0.141737495 0.52058258 0.2906524187 0.57027453 0.2891290
8    H 0.54025639 0.36612370 0.36154801 0.002325156 0.01804719 0.3545106335 0.31464347 0.1252540
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Jon Spring's answer and his idea of indexing `Year` as numeric levels of a factor. However, the previous answers used the `df` to calculate the difference of a site between consecutive years, rather the Euclidean distances calculated by `dist()`.
This may not be the most elegant answer, and the idea is Jon's, and it works.
Here goes:

```
# gather to long form to calculate dist.
df = df %>% gather (key = "Year", value = "Value", c(2:last_col()))

# calculate dist and set as a df
dist_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(YrSi = paste(substr(Year, 3, 4), Site)) %>%
  select(-Year, -Site) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "YrSi") %>%
  dist() %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  as.data.frame()


#Create a new df that takes the dist() and rearranges is in a workable way
#Two cols for year ("Year" and "Year2") are set as numeric levels of these two
#factors, and a "diff" col is calculated based on these. 

dist_consec_df = dist_df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("YrSi") %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year", "Site"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(ifelse(Year == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year), sprintf("20%s", Year)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  gather(key = "YrSi", value = "Dist",c(3:last_col())) %>% 
  separate(YrSi, c("Year2", "Site2"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Year2 = as.numeric(ifelse(Year2 == "99", sprintf("19%s", Year2), sprintf("20%s", Year2)))) %>% # Change to yyyy
  mutate (Year = as.factor(Year),
          Year_index = as.numeric(Year),
          Year2 = as.factor(Year2),
          Year_index2 = as.numeric(Year2),
          diff = abs(Year_index2-Year_index)) %>% 
  subset (Site == Site2) %>% 
  filter (diff==1, Year_index2 > Year_index) %>% 
  group_by(Site)  %>% 
  select (-Year,  -Site2, -Year_index,-Year_index2, -diff) %>% 
  spread (key = "Year2", value = "Dist")
```

Output

```
  Site  `2000` `2001` `2006`  `2008` `2011`   `2013` `2016` `2019`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     0.501  0.379  0.474  0.0574  0.895  0.483    0.364   0.341
2 B     0.500  0.503  0.224  0.105   0.470  0.797    0.654   0.204
3 C     0.627  0.0650 0.197  0.0523  0.354  0.339    0.0528  0.164
4 D     0.305  0.142  0.816  0.0607  0.212  0.105    0.771   0.453
5 E     0.542  0.102  0.0866 0.0888  0.272  0.000822 0.0449  0.216
6 F     0.0942 0.233  0.200  0.592   0.812  0.396    0.357   0.677
7 G     0.354  0.0790 0.626  0.142   0.521  0.291    0.570   0.289
8 H     0.540  0.366  0.362  0.00233 0.0180 0.355    0.315   0.125
```